# Can I used iMac's Image Capture app to import video from my camcorder to iMovie '09?

Tags: imac, imovie

I'm trying to import video from my Canon camcorder (Vixia HF R600) to iMovie '09 on my iMac (an older model but updated to OS X 10.9.5) The camera recognizes the USB input but the computer does not recognize the camera. Can I import the video to iMovie using the "Image Capture" app?

Answer (score 1):

You would need the iMovie 10 installed on your iMac.

If you have a qualifying system and OS you get it for free, otherwise it is $15.

Be aware that you might have 2 iMovies apps in your Application folder. The older ver9 and the newer one v10. Look for it.

Apple shows it as [supported](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204202) (Canon VIXIA HF R600
Format: AVCHD / MPEG-4) in the iMovie 10 (but not in iMovie 9)

Comment: If I answered your question please mark it as done, so our search engine does not keep brining it up as not done. Or mark you answer as done.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I have solved the problem of importing video from a camcorder to iMovie '09, but I had to do it sideways. iMovie '09 would not allow me to import it directly. Image Capture would not import my raw footage directly but it did import it to iPhoto. From there, iMovie automatically imported my video from iPhoto to iMovie. Viola!

I'm now editing a project for the first time and learning as I go.

Thanks to those who offered help and support!